# max of the averages excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi guys I have a table similar to this:

```
Company / Score 1/ Score 2/ Score 3
Apple   / 5  / 4 / 3
Banana  / 3  / 6 / 6
Kiwi    / 0  / 5 / 1
```

Is there a way to find the best performing company from this list using the averages of their score in one formula without using helper column? So for the above example my return will be company Banana- because it gives me the biggest score when averaged all three columns. Also by average I mean sum/count if > 0 so for KIWI the average is 3 not 2.

Comment: Do you always have only three columns?

Comment: Surely banana has highest ...6+6+3 = 15 /3 = 5...

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean but to clarify the above is the scores for the one element in my assessment which I have 3 columns to get average from and always be 3. for another element I will have 5 score columns to get average from but it will also always be 5 column for that.

Comment: Oops, sorry yes banana has the highest.

Comment: Is this your question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50482513/4961700

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your scores are non-negative and start at B2:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(MAX(MMULT(B2:D4,--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B2:D2)))>0))/MMULT(--(B2:D4>0),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B2:D2)))>0))),MMULT(B2:D4,--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B2:D2)))>0))/MMULT(--(B2:D4>0),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B2:D2)))>0)),0))
```

This will expand to however many rows/columns you need. Keep in mind that it will return the first high score in case of a tie. Also, if there's a possibility of getting all zeros, you should wrap the array passed to `MAX` with an `IFERROR` (this formula will need to be entered as an array formula (`ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`):

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(MAX(IFERROR(MMULT(B2:D4,--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B2:D2)))>0))/MMULT(--(B2:D4>0),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B2:D2)))>0)),0)),MMULT(B2:D4,--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B2:D2)))>0))/MMULT(--(B2:D4>0),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B2:D2)))>0)),0))
```

Comment: Neat! this worked for me even without ctrl+shift+enter.  I was thinking of going down the road of `INDIRECT` but seemed like too much effort :) +1 for getting it to work

Comment: @chancea Right on. I edited it with a couple other considerations.

Comment: Quick clarification if i use this formula in different sheet than data sheet, then where should my sheet name goes? I tried this but didn't work:  
     =INDEX(Solution!A2:A30;MATCH(MAX(MMULT(Solution!B2:D30;--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:Solution!"&COLUMNS(B2:D30)))>0))/MMULT(--(Solution!B2:D30>0);--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:Solution!"&COLUMNS(B2:D30)))>0)));MMULT(Solution!B2:D30;--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:Solution!"&COLUMNS(B2:D30)))>0))/MMULT(--(Solution!B2:D30>0);--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:Solution!"&COLUMNS(B2:D30)))>0));0))

Comment: Put the worksheet identifier anywhere you call your range:
=INDEX(Solution!A2:A4,MATCH(MAX(MMULT(Solution!B2:D4,--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(Solution!B2:D2)))>0))/MMULT(--(Solution!B2:D4>0),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(Solution!B2:D2)))>0))),MMULT(Solution!B2:D4,--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(Solution!B2:D2)))>0))/MMULT(--(Solution!B2:D4>0),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(Solution!B2:D2)))>0)),0))

Answer (score 1):

With Hard-Coding the array to 3 columns we can use an array formula.

Note array formulas need to be entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

This also assumes the columns are A,B,C,D respectively.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX((B:B+C:C+D:D)/MAX((IF(B:B>0,1,0)+IF(C:C>0,1,0)+IF(D:D>0,1,0)),1)),(B:B+C:C+D:D)/MAX((IF(B:B>0,1,0)+IF(C:C>0,1,0)+IF(D:D>0,1,0)),1),0))
```

Slight explanation:

1. `(B:B+C:C+D:D)` = the sum of the rows as an array
2. `MAX((IF(B:B>0,1,0)+IF(C:C>0,1,0)+IF(D:D>0,1,0)),1)` = the total numbers we are going to sum in the array (3 for Apple, Banana, 2 for Kiwi).  The max is to get rid of any Divide by zero errors
3. `{1}/{2}` = Average for each row
4. We can then do `Max({3})` to see the highest average
5. `INDEX(A:A,{4},{3})` will find the respective company based on the highest average we found

Supporting Screenshots:

[image]
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>
[image]